# How to use grpc Status Details in package io.grpc

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am writing a java client which communicates to a server using gRPC. The server (written in rust) returns structured data in the case of errors using the [Status `Details` field](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/status.proto#L46).

I see that [`com.google.rpc.Status`](http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/rpc/Status.html#getDetailsList--) has a `getDetails` method for accessing the "Any" type. However, my generated java code along with all of the exampls gRPC java clients I've found are using `io.grpc.*` and [`io.grpc.Status`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/Status.java) does **not** have any way of accessing `Details`.

**How can I access Details?** Either by using io.grpc.* or somehow changing my generated grpc client to use com.google.rpc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`google.rpc.Status` is propagated via gRPC metadata. The [`io.grpc.StatusProto`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/protobuf/StatusProto.html) class has utilities to process `google.rpc.Status` messages. Using the utilities is important because they verify the `google.rpc.Status` matches the `io.grpc.Status` to avoid security vulnerabilities caused by mixing the two.

An interceptor would use `StatusProto.fromStatusAndTrailers(Status, Metadata)` and an application would use `StatusProto.fromThrowable(Throwable)`. `StatusRuntimeException` in grpc-java includes the metadata, so the status is able to be extracted.

This is related to the [rich error handling in gRPC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750825/4690866).

Comment: Heck yeah- it works! I didn't think to explore the "_Proto" classes. Thank you!