# Is there any way to use rich error model for grpc service in armeria?

Tags: exception, grpc, armeria

I am using Armeria 1.3.0 and protobuf for a gRPC service.
I've tried to use [rich error model](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error/#richer-error-model) when handling exceptions but I think Armeria seems to only support standard error model.

How can I use rich error model in Armeria? I want to return custom error code/message and more details about error when exception occurred.

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: Hi! What is a rich model?

Comment: Looks like this one: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error/#richer-error-model

Comment: That's right. There's some example using google protobuf according to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748745/pattern-for-rich-error-handling-in-grpc

Comment: Yeah, did you try to specify such information in `Metadata`? I think it should be doable with Armeria.

Comment: I tried to use Metadata but it is only possible  when used with responseObserver.onError method not exceptionMapping of GrpcService.Builder. The exceptionMapping method only returns Status, so I tricky tried like this, `return Status.INTERNAL.asRuntimeException(metadata).getStatus()` but metadata.get method returns null in the grpc client.

Comment: I looked into GrpcServiceBuilder related codes of armeria. I think these are the reason that the metadata doesn't have any. `doClose(GrpcStatus.fromThrowable(statusFunction, exception), metadata);` of `close(Throwable exception, Metadata metadata)` method in the ArmeriaServerCall class

Comment: I have created a new issue for this question: https://github.com/line/armeria/issues/3307 However, do you think the workaround mentioned in the issue page will work for your case? If so, let me add a proper answer to this question.

Comment: I think your mention in the issue page would work for me if the exceptionMapping method is also included in the update item list. Thanks.

Comment: I see. Let me add an answer that explains the current state of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not possible to attach arbitrary gRPC `Metadata` to a gRPC error response till Armeria 1.5.0, but you will be able to do so from the next minor update (1.6.0):

```java
GrpcService
    .builder()
    .addExceptionMapping(MyException.class, (cause, metadata) -> {
        metadata.put(MY_KEY, myValue)
        return Status.XXX.withDescription("...");
    })
    ...
```

See https://github.com/line/armeria/pull/3329 for the detail.