# Sending the error in case of GRPC with full duplex ReadStream and WriteStream

Tags: vert.x, grpc-java

Can someone help me understand how I can send the error in case of full duplex with ReadStream and WriteStream.

This is the sample proto file.

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.pace.vertx.grpc.generated";
package com.pace.vertx.grpc.generated;


service ArrangementService {
  rpc GetArrangementDetails (stream ArrangementRequest) returns (stream ArrangementAllDetails) {}
}

message ArrangementRequest {
  string arrangementId = 1;
}

message ArrangementAllDetails {
  string arrangementDetails = 1;
}
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
    BindableService vertxArrangementServiceGrpc = new VertxArrangementServiceGrpc.ArrangementServiceVertxImplBase() {
        @Override
        public void getArrangementDetails(ReadStream<ArrangementRequest> request, WriteStream<ArrangementAllDetails> response) {
            Pump.pump((ReadStream)request, response).start();
            request.handler(arrangementRequest -> {
                couchbaseDAO.getReactiveCollection()
                        .get(arrangementRequest.getArrangementId())
                        .map(getResult -> getResult
                                .contentAsObject()
                                .removeKey("key_tx")
                                .removeKey("version"))
                        .subscribe(
                                jsonObject -> response.end(ArrangementAllDetails.newBuilder().setArrangementDetails(jsonObject.toString()).build()),
                                error -> ?????
                        );

            });
        }
    }
            .withCompression("gzip");
```

How can I send the error back in the error subscription block ?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750825/11697987) to "Pattern for rich error handling in gRPC" question might be helpful.